# Registering a Custom Module in IIS 7

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I've created a custom module for IIS that I want to run some tests on.  I created a new directory inside inetpub/wwwroot called demo and added a new site called MDemo.  I added me DLL to the /bin folder.  This directory now contains 2 files: default.aspx and bin/mydll.

I went to Modules on the site and tried to "Add Managed Module".  My module is not showing up in the list.  I tried to add it to the GAC but I can't figure out how.  I attempted to use Mscorcfg.msc but .NET Framework Configuration does not show up as an option.

How can I get this DLL to show up in the list and add as a managed module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "Managed Module" means that it is in the GAC.  You can get the dll into the GAC by using GacUtil or by creating a "Setup Project" (under "Other Project Types") in Visual Studio.
See http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2008/11/10/creating-a-setup-project-for-iis-extensions-using-visual-studio-2008.aspx

Comment: @Dexter, did getting it installed in the GAC make it show up in the types drop down list in IIS7? I'm trying to do this as well and I have the same problem - my type doesn't show up.  My assembly is in the GAC though.

Comment: Update: fixed.  Root web app was .net 2, my module was .net 4, which is why it didn't show up.  Hurrrr....

Answer (score 1):

I found [this article](http://www.codekicks.com/2007/04/creating-shared-assembly-or-gac.html) about signing an assembly and adding it to the GAC.

It's best to create a separate Class library project that will contain your IIS Module. You'll have to create a certificate for it so you can sign it. Then you can use the compiled dll and add it to the GAC.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is actually what I'm trying to do, but my class doesn't show up in the Type drop-down despite being in the bin folder of the site I'm trying to add it to.  My preference is not to add it to the GAC yet, I want to test it just within this site first to make sure it works the way I need.  Any thoughts on how to get it to show up?